# Unable to install sbt 0.13.16 using SDK Manager

Tags: sbt, sdkman

I'm trying to install sbt 0.13.16 using SDK Manager.

```
$ sdk install sbt 0.13.16

Stop! sbt 0.13.16 is not available. Possible causes:
 * 0.13.16 is an invalid version
 * sbt binaries are incompatible with Darwin
```

Below is the SDK details -

```
$ sdk version

SDKMAN 5.5.13+272
```

Any reason, why I'm not able to install sbt 0.13.16 using sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to install this version because it is not available.

To find out all the SBT candidate versions available for installation run the command:

```
sdk list sbt
```